# How to make a table view in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am net even sure what it is called but I want to make a table fully dynamic. Where the top is named "tier" and the values are taken from a database table named "tier". On the side there are the "items" from the "items" table from the database. I have also made an intermediate table for the many to many relationship **An item have man tiers a tier has many items**. In this intermediate table i am storing the item id and the tier id.

I have manged to display the tiers and the items dynamically according to the database, but im not sure how to fill up that data now.

[image]

What i want is to take the values from the intermidate table and insert it. The value is a boolean so either true or false. For example i want to check if the Silver tier has a photo, if it is equals to true i want to display it. How can i do such a thing because i cant wrap my head around it.

Here is the code i did to generate the table, if there is any improvement i can make please tell me i want to learn to code better if possible.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        //To show all of the tiers
        foreach ($tier as $tier) {
            $counter ++;
            ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $tier->name; ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            foreach ($itemTier as $value) {
                if($tier->id == $value->itemId){
                    echo $value->value;
                }
            }
            ?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //Showing all of the options
    foreach ($item as $item) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $item->name; ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            //Displaying the extra columns
            for($i = 0; $i< $counter; $i++){
                ?>
                <td>
                </td>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Daan I knew there was something already invented! thank you ill give it a look and see if it fits my need.

Comment: @Daan I stil encounter the same problem tho :/ i Just dont know how to put the value of Silver - Pohoto inside of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$variable = 'Hello World';
?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <? echo $variable; ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know how to do that, I did it like that, what i want is too compare two values together of the table and check if the value of them.

Comment: This does not solves the problem of makind a table in php! It's a Hello world example in php!!